# Finding an orthogonal and diagonal matrix given eigenvalues/vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

So for a symmetric matrix A I am given the eigenvalues $\lambda_1=3$ and $\lambda_2=-1$ where {[1 2 -1],[0 1 1]} is a basis for $E_3$ and {[-3 1 -1]} is a basis for $E_{-1}$.

I have the diagonal matrix D:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and from using the Gram-Schmidt method for the eigenvectors given I received the matrix Q
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1\over \sqrt6 & -1\over \sqrt66 &  -3\over \sqrt11 \\
\sqrt{2\over3} & 2\sqrt2\over\sqrt33 & 1\over \sqrt11 \\
-1\over \sqrt6 & 7\over\sqrt66 & -1\over \sqrt11 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I believe I have done all of my math correctly however when trying to solve for A using QDQ^T=A while I get a symmetric matrix with the correct eigenvalues I don't get the same eigenvectors I started with instead I get
[$-1\over3 $ 0 1], [$1\over3$ 1 0], [3 -1 1]

Comment: Please add the details about which basis you obtained from Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: The second column of $Q$ is incorrect. It should be ${1 \over \sqrt{66}} [1 -4 \ 7]$.

Comment: The eigenvectors corresponding to $\lambda = 3$ that you started with are not orthogonal.

Comment: Are you sure of your vector $(1,2,-1)$?

Comment: @DavidRaveh I normalized the vector [-3 1 -1] and got the third column as a result. As for the other basis, using gram Schmidt I got [1 2 -1] and [-1/6 2/3 7/6] which I normalized and got columns 1 and 2 of Q.

Comment: @HosamH These were the vectors I was given so I'll ask my prof about it thank you.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Yes these were the vectors given to me but I'll check with my prof about this.